# using VPN on the phone . Am I identified by the network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am connecting the network cable to my personal modem and connecting the work computer to the modem ( using the modem as a switch) and connecting my phone via wifi to the same modem. And then using a vpn application on my phone to bypass the blocked websites. The question is : Can they identify the websites I visit?

Comment: Why not just view the sites on your phone during your lunch break rather than trying to subvert your company's security policy?

Answer (score 1):

In the immediate term - no, if you have disabled your prozy and disconnected your machine from the network, then the odds are that your browsing cannot be seen in real time.

If your IT department have auditing tools installed, they can go back and look at what you have looked at after your machine is reconnected to the network though... even if you wipe your browsing history.

If this is a company PC and you are violating your IT terms of use wilfully - you can be fired for this.

The sites that have been blocked by your IT department have been blocked for a reason - so stop trying to bypass security that is there for a reason.  If you need these sites for work related usage, talk to your manager and get the site unblocked (as long as your request is reasonable)